# Set PATH variable so that it is detected in all applications, even outside terminal. (El Captain)

Tags: macos, path, temperature, emacs, environment-variables

My `~/etc/path` looks as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

**The Problem:**

When I type `echo $PATH` into terminal, I get back:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

And this persists for every application started in the terminal. For instance, if I type `emacs`, and then do:

```
M-x getenv PATH
```

My output is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However, if I start up emacs using launchpad instead of terminal and once again enter `M-x getenv PATH`, my output is instead `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

As you can see my change to `~/etc/path`, which was the addition of `/usr/local/bin`, is missing.

**Another Example:**

I use a Firefox plugin called *vimperator* which emulates vim functionality in Firefox. It has a feature that allows the user to edit webpage input in vim. However, this does not seem to work on OS X. On a hunch I type the command `!echo $PATH` into vimperator and see the following: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Of course, since the symlink called `gvim`, which points to `macvim`, was created and placed into `/usr/local/bin` by brew, this behavior makes sense. What I don't understand is why the `PATH` is read the way it is.

**Solutions that I have tried:**

- I have obviously restarted my machine.

**EDIT (As requested by now deleted comment):**

using `sysctl user.cs_path` in the terminal brings up:

```
user.cs_path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: @fd0 Sure. I'm done, and this is the exact path that I have been getting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `loginwindow` process sets a user's environment. It sets the variables TMPDIR and PATH, consults Directory Services and sets SHELL HOME USER LOGNAME . PATH is set to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` unless modified by launchd (in the more current versions of OS X). This is the PATH variable available to the user's processes unless modified by that particular process (`cron` as an example sets the PATH to `/bin:/usr/bin`).

Terminal emulator applications start your shell as a login shell thus the PATH is modified by reading the various shell startup file. Any process started by your shell now inherits the new PATH variable. Other applications using a shell do not read any shell config files and use those environment variables available in the current environment. An application may modify the environment by using the `LSEnvironment` key in their `Info.plist`.

As of Yosemite, you can change the PATH variable in the following form.

```
sudo launchctl config user path <path>
```

in your case you want /usr/local/bin at the front of the path.

```
sudo launchctl config user path /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

`reboot` your system and the new PATH will be set by `loginwindow`.

Comment: Does this still work in Big Sur / Monterey? I'm having trouble getting it to have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Run this:</s>

```bash
launchctl setenv PATH "$PATH"
```

**EDIT**: That no longer works. Use this with Bash instead:

```bash
CURRENT="$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print PATH" ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist)"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set PATH $CURRENT:/your/path/here:/another/path/maybe" ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Then log out and log in again.

*Note*: You may want to replace `$CURRENT:/your/path/here:/another/path/maybe` with just a list of paths like `:/your/path/here:/another/path/maybe`, but that is a bad idea becase it will erase all paths already stored.

This uses [User Session Environment Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-113982).

Comment: I tried both simply running the command, as well as adding it to both my .profile and .bash_profile. The PATH is still set to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in Eclipse, Vimperator (firefox), and Emacs. The strange thing is, if I use the option to execute a shell script in either Emacs or Vimperator, running `echo $PATH` gets me `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. However, running `launchctl getenv PATH` produces `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`; I don't know how to execute a shell script in Eclipse. I restarted after I made the changes to my dot files of course.

Comment: This is also what is displayed if I type `echo $PATH` in the terminal.

Comment: What exactly is that command supposed to do?

Comment: @Allan I did come across that command as well while googling for answers. Apparently it used to set environmental variables back in 10.8. Now it doesn't work.

Comment: The command was supposed to notify launchctl about the new `PATH` variable, but apparently that doesn't work anymore. I updated my answer with a new solution.