# How to revert launchctl PATH to defaults?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, launchd, path

There are many questions and commentary about using `launchctl setenv PATH /path/to/include` in order to have GUI apps inherit user-specified paths. I did this about four years ago, and the changes I added have persisted to 10.11.6 (current OS). Unfortunately for me, I have long forgotten these settings until recently...

None of the man pages or commentary indicates how to revert these changes to factory defaults. For instance, running `launchctl getenv PATH` yields:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/libpcap/bin:/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/sbin:/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/bin:/usr/local/opt/flex/bin:/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Programs:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS`

Running `launchctl setenv PATH [blank]` is evidently an error, demanding a non-blank value. I'm also hesitant to experiment with this much because I don't know whether there is a macOS default setting for this key-value pair.

Can someone please tell me how I can flush the current contents of `launchctl getenv PATH` or to return its content to what would appear in a fresh install? I would rather not replace what's currently there with the default paths from `/etc/profile` and the like, unless those are the self-same values that appear when running `launchctl getenv PATH` on a fresh installation.

#### Edit

Running `launchctl unsetenv PATH` did clear out the variable, but it did not persist after reboot - i.e., the same path values returned after a restart.

Answer (score 3):

What ended up working to restore to default "factory presets" for me was to run:

`sudo launchctl config user path /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

This is not unlike the advice seen here ([Set PATH variable so that it is detected in all applications, even outside terminal. (El Captain)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243322/set-path-variable-so-that-it-is-detected-in-all-applications-even-outside-termi)). But some lingering questions remain:

1. Does this procedure **restore** what was already in the key-value pair of `user path`, or does it enact a new setting that would otherwise be empty?
2. Where, i.e., in what file or database, is this key-value stored?

Comment: You can set the same value as the default would be, however, you will mask the real default after the `launchctl config user path` call (this will be a problem after the default changes). - FYI: If you have ran the `launchctl config user path` you can revert changes by the `defaults delete /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist PathEnvironmentVariable` command.